# the permission pages_show_list declined

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

i have submitted my app to verification and have advanced permission over pages_show_list
but after login web when i debug the user token and see it's persmission it gives me that the permission pages_show_list is declined here is my function ;

```
FB.login(function(response)
  {
  if (response.authResponse)
  {
  window.location.href = url; 
          }
  }   
      ,{ auth_type: 'reauthenticate' },{scope: 'public_profile,email,pages_show_list', return_scopes: true});
```

So how can i get the permission

thanks

Comment: This function takes _two_ parameters, the callback function, and an options object. You are currently passing _three_ parameters  - your callback function, an object containing only the authtype setting - and then a third one, that no one really cares about here. So effectively, you did not ask for _any_ permission at all with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response it was a great reminder